# Efficient js image slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, slideshow

I've been looking around for an efficient js responsive image slideshow gallery but I cannot make up my mind.

Neat ones such as [ResponsiveSlides](http://responsiveslides.com) come at the price of loading all the images beforehand. When the page loads, all the images are loaded as well. Since I have 50-60 images per slideshow, every page requires several MB to be downloaded when the page is loaded, resulting in delays and bandwidth consumption.

Do you have a more efficient strategy/library in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want an image slide with lazy loading so that images don't load until they enter the viewport. I know [Owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html) has it as an option and it's also responsive. I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this gallery.....
http://johnpolacek.github.io/ResponsiveThumbnailGallery/

Comment: This is not an aswer.